# How to avoid some values in the legend?

Tags: r

The piece of code given below will read and show image of the file with a legend.
how can I tell R to not take into consideration the values of ,for example -9999 ,or any other values when drawing legend.

```
conne <- file("C:\\DEM.bin", "rb")
image(t(t(y)),ylim=c(1,0))
image.plot(t(t(y)), add = FALSE, legend.shrink = 0.9,legend.width = 1.2,
           legend.mar = NULL, graphics.reset = FALSE, horizontal = FALSE, bigplot = NULL,
           smallplot = NULL,legend.only = FALSE,lab.breaks=NULL, axis.args=NULL))
```

Comment: Why t(t(y)), transposing two times leads to the same matrix...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's create a mockup dataset (your dataset is not reproducible):

```
m = matrix(runif(100), 10, 10)
m[sample(1:10, size = 2), sample(1:10, size = 2)] = -9999
```

matrix `m` now contains two values you do not want to plot:

[image]

The solution is to make them `NA`, in which case R will know they are missing values:

```
m[m == -9999] <- NA
image(m)
```

[image]

The `NA` values are now ignored, and replaced by white pixels, and your image looks normal. If there are multiple values you want to make NA:

```
m[m %in% c(-9999, 1e30, -1)] <- NA
```

now all the values in the list are marked as `NA`.